# how can i insert javascript $.post result into textfield

Tags: javascript, php

how can i insert javascript $.post result into textfield. below is my code. But it is not working

```
$.post("scripts/service_getmaxPrice.php", {id:id}, function(data){
    $("#maxPrice").innerhtml.html(data);
    document.getElementById('maxPrice').value =html(data);
});
```

html code is

```
<tr><td class="ttxt" style="text-align:right;">Maximum price</td><td><input type="text" id="maxPrice" class="txt" name="maxPrice" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure where you got the random smatterings of code there, but it's really quite simple in jQuery:

```
$.post("scripts/service_getmaxPrice.php", {id:id}, function(data){
  $('#maxPrice').val(data);
});
```

If you were populating a div or something else not a form field, it'd be `$('#maxPrice').html(data)` or `$('#maxPrice').text(data)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.post("scripts/service_getmaxPrice.php", {id:id}, function(data){
    $("#maxPrice").val(data);
});
```